# What is the format accepted by System.Net.Mail.MailAddress' parser?

Tags: .net, validation, email

I'm working on an app that's using [System.Net.Mail.MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) and friends for sending emails. Does that parser implement the full [RFC5322](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt) or a subset or what? The MSDN is not very forthcoming on this topic.

Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Get and install RedGate's Reflector, then navigate to the System.Net.Mail namespace and look at the code to see what it does. I'd do this but I'm at home on my Mac right now.

Comment: Maybe I'm strange, but I'd rather see a document (preferably by MS or ECMA) stating that the damn thing "accepts RFCsuch-and-such addresses except sections X, Y, and Z because the IETF doesn't know sh*t about the internet" than having to disassemble the thing.

Comment: Agreed, but absent such documentation -- and maybe even with it -- looking at the code would answer the question definitively.

Comment: ... for this specific implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've wrote a little snippet to test the function:

```
foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(32,128-32))
{
    char c = (char)i;
    string addr = String.Format("par.t1{0}pa.r{0}t2@example.com", c);
    try
    {
        var mailAddr = new MailAddress(addr);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MailAddress failed '{0}' ({1}): {2}", c, i, addr);
    }
}
```

With the following results on 3.5 SP1:

```
MailAddress failed ' ' (32): par.t1 pa.r t2@example.com
MailAddress failed '"' (34): par.t1"pa.r"t2@example.com
MailAddress failed '(' (40): par.t1(pa.r(t2@example.com
MailAddress failed ')' (41): par.t1)pa.r)t2@example.com
MailAddress failed ',' (44): par.t1,pa.r,t2@example.com
MailAddress failed ':' (58): par.t1:pa.r:t2@example.com
MailAddress failed ';' (59): par.t1;pa.r;t2@example.com
MailAddress failed '<' (60): par.t1<pa.r<t2@example.com
MailAddress failed '>' (62): par.t1>pa.r>t2@example.com
MailAddress failed '@' (64): par.t1@pa.r@t2@example.com
MailAddress failed '[' (91): par.t1[pa.r[t2@example.com
MailAddress failed '\' (92): par.t1\pa.r\t2@example.com
MailAddress failed ']' (93): par.t1]pa.r]t2@example.com
MailAddress failed '⌂' (127): par.t1⌂pa.r⌂t2@example.com
```

Also it doesn't seem to support "quoted-string" local-parts, like `"blah"@example.com`.

I don't think a validator could accept any less before becoming unusable.

Answer (score 4):

In the discussion thread on [Dominic Sayers isemail article](http://www.dominicsayers.com/isemail/), Jerry O'Brien said that he read Dominic's RFC compliance test cases against the `System.Net.MailAddress` class:

> `System.Net.MailAddress` is only 59%
>   compliant with the RFC specifications.
>   Follow-up comments noted the specific
>   cases where it generated false
>   positives and false negatives.

The RFCs are extremely weak on what constitutes a valid email email address. They allow a range of unusual and unpopular formats. So I guess the real question is, is `System.Net.MailAddress` good enough in a majority of real-world situations?

Comment: Thanks for this interesting link! Also, a good question about the parser being "good enough". The specific implementation I tested was good enough for the application I did. As I tried to explain in the comments to the question, the broader issue for me is that this, like many other places in the BCL, is woefully inadequate documentation; creating unnecessary dependencies on implementation details (see the reflector comment).

Comment: I totally agree with you. In places where standards exist (things like date formats, URIs, email addresses, etc.) it would be nice to know what the design specification for the class are -- and published unit tests, too!

Comment: I use this method, but test@test passes validation.  Bummer.