# .NET: Email Address Parsing - save with RegExp or just Try/Catch around Mail.MailAddressParser?

Tags: .net, parsing, email-validation, email-parsing

what would you recommend to get a simple result like "IsMailValid?" -> true|false?

- is it save to use a regExp
- is it better to use .NET's System...Mail.MailAddressParser with a simple try/catch around it?

Since speed is not that relevant, i think going the way with MailAddressParser would be OK?

Regards

John

Answer (score 1):

Given your requirements specifically speed not being necessary, I would use the Mail.MailAddressParser with a try/catch.  It's guaranteed to filter out anything the .NET runtime can't recognize as a valid email address, and its much simpler.

A good regex will likely do the same, but a bad regex will give you false positives, false negatives, or both.

The performance cost in handling exceptions would make me go the other way if speed were a factor, but in this case, with your requirements, less code, more readable code, and it "just works" all balance out the performance factor.

***Clarification:***

I'm assuming your intended code would look like this:

```
try
{
   System.Net.Mail.MailAddress address = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(somestring);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
   // handle invalid email addresses here.
}
```

And my recommendation is only for this situation.  This is an **intentional** exception to the best practices of not using Exceptions where other methods would work and ***only*** suggested because of the explicit statement that performance is not a factor.

Comment: Few clarifications: MailAddressParser is internal class and cannot be used directly. Also see [System.Net.MailAddress is only 59% compliant with the RFC specifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528090/what-is-the-format-accepted-by-system-net-mail-mailaddress-parser)

Comment: I am aware of the System.Net.MailAddress not being fully compliant, but assuming he is going to use .NET code to send an email to this address, I fall back to my statement that "it's guaranteed to filter out anything the .NET runtime can't recognize as a valid email address."

Answer (score 0):

It is against .NET Best Practices to use exceptions where you expect failures on a regular basis. The reason is exceptions are very expensive.

I would use a Regular Expression in compiled mode to filter out the bad email addresses.

Something like this would work perfectly:

```
Private Function ValidEmail(ByVal Email As String) As Boolean
    If Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(Trim(Email), "^\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\b$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.Compiled) = False Then
        Return False
    Else
        Return True
    End If
End Function
```